# android onCheckboxClicked hide /show achartengine

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, achartengine

I need to hide a linechart when user click a button, 
and show it when user clicks again. Here is my code:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
     Cursor cursor = getCursor();
     id = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID);
     ect = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TEMPER);
     battery = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BATTERY);

     XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
     XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
     mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
     mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

     boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

      switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.check_temp:
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            if (checked) {
              TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
              while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                     series1.add(cursor.getDouble(id), cursor.getDouble(ect));
              }
              dataset.addSeries(series1);
              renderer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
              mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
            }else{
              mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(renderer1); //not working
            }
           break;
          case R.id.check_battery:  //not working
             if(checked) {...}
          } //end of switch
    GraphicalView viewchart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer);
    chartContainer.addView(viewchart);
} //end of onCheckboxClicked fxn
```

1. mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(renderer1) not working.
2. checkbox only show firest time linechart , even I check another checkbox ,

it's still not show second linechart?

PS : I found the other way can fix it. so just ignore my question. Thanks.

Comment: please post your solution as answer and accept it, if it worked.

Comment: switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.check_temp:
                if(isChecked) {
                    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
                    dataset.addSeries(series1);
                    chartView.repaint();
                }else {
                    dataset.removeSeries(series1);
                    mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
                    chartView.repaint();
                }
            break;